# Use curve in d3 force directed graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I want to visualize some data via d3 force layout.

However, the links connecting nodes are straight lines. But the data 
may have multiple edges connecting two nodes. So straight lines in 
force layout cannot correctly display all of them. I tried to append 
path to links rather than line. But it didn't work. I don't know 
whether that was because I was using it in the wrong way or force 
layout doesn't accept path as links.

Comment: A simplified example showing the code you tried and the result (perhaps via http://bl.ocks.org/ or http://jsfiddle.net) would go a long way towards getting people to help you.

Comment: There's an example of a [force layout with curved edges](http://bl.ocks.org/1153292) linked from the [gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery).

Comment: I have a similar requirement. Pls see my question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853134/enclosing-the-nodes-of-a-d3-force-directed-graph-in-a-circle-or-a-polygon-or-a-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use svg : path insted of line

```
var viz = d3.select("body")
    .insert("svg:svg", "h2")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var path = svg.selectAll("path").data(force.links()).enter()
                .append("svg:path").attr("source", function(d) {
                    return d.source.id;
                }).attr("target", function(d) {
                    return d.target.id;
                }).attr("class", "link").attr('marker-end', 'url(#head)');
```

here **source** and **target** are the **nodes** , curve specified in the '**d**' attribute of '**svg:path**' and **marker-end** attribute is for arrow head